# Check for empty or blank links in all html files in root directory using gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I have a lot of HTML documents in the root of my projects. Let's take a simple skeleton HTML document like so:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->



        <a href="#">hello</a>
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <a href="#">hello</a>
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <a href="#">hello</a>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now before I send all these files to the development team, I am assigned with the task of checking that there are no links which have no href, and empty href, or have an empty fragment as an href. I.e.,

Basically, there cannot be likes like so:

```
<a href="">
```

or

```
<a href="#">
```

or

```
 <a>
```

I found [this gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-pages#checklinks) and but I have a few issues with it. Let's have a look at the gulp file first:

```
gulp.task("checkDev", function(callback) {
  var options = {
    pageUrls: [
      'http://localhost:8080/Gulp-Test/index.html'
    ],
    checkLinks: true,
    summary: true
  };
  checkPages(console, options, callback);
});
```

Note that when you pass the option `checkLinks: true` , it's not just for the `a` tags , it for all of the tags mentioned [on this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-pages#checklinks). The plugin doesn't have a problem if the `<a>` tag is empty or just has a # or is not present at all.

See what happens when I run the gulp tasks:

[image: The result of running the gulp plugin]

So what I would like instead is, if only the `a` links could be checked and if the `<a>` tag doesn't have an href or a blank value or just a #, then it should throw an error or show it in the summary report.

Lastly, see in the sample of the gulp file how I am passing the pageUrl (i.e. the pages to be checked basically) like so:

```
 pageUrls: [
          'http://localhost:8080/Gulp-Test/index.html'
        ],
```

How do I instead tell this plugin to check for all the `.html` files inside the `Gulp-Test` directory ?

So to summarize my question: how do I get this plugin to throw an error (i.e. show in the summary report) when it sees an `<a>` without a `href` or a href that is blank or has a value of # and also how do I tell this plugin to check for all .html files inside a directory.

Comment: looks like you found the answer yourself in your last edit. check out this option https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-pages#noemptyfragments. I suggest answering yourself and accept that answer, so other people will be able to easily find it (and also so you can get them sweet points :)).

Comment: @Ness close but still a long shot from what i want to achieve , i have re phrased my question .

Comment: @Ness Thanks for the tip , but with `noEmptyFragments: true,` only <a href="#"></a> , will fail .. but <a></a> and  <a href=""></a> , will pass.

Comment: The [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/DavidAnson/check-pages). I suggest downloading a copy and start coding. :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Not that pro yet ! ;) .. or i would't be asking the question in the first place lol

Comment: Well the fact is, that the plugin wasn't created with your requirements in mind, so I'm guessing there's no answer to your question that will meet them. I think that looking at the code this plugin uses would be a great learning opportunity; it's well structured and well commented. Plus you can always ask questions here as you find parts you can't understand!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, `Well the fact is, that the plugin wasn't created with your requirements in mind,` Thanks , i know that , i was still hoping that there would be a work around using this plugin , and i don't feel like its just my requirement , but rather a scenario that quite a few developers would face. `I think that looking at the code this plugin uses would be a great learning opportunity; it's well structured and well commented. Plus you can always ask questions here as you find parts you can't understand!` , i'am all for learning , ... but in this instance its not practical for me .

Comment: In one of my projects i was required to test a web project for basic SEO. I had to look for images without alternate text, links without title and such. I believe it is something very similar to your task. What i used was selenium framework and it worked just great! If you don't need to stick to your gulp plugin i can explain my solution in an answer.

Comment: @Kyborek absolutly go ahead :) .. as for gulp i was hope this could be done in gulp itself , need not be this plugin. I wanted to stick to gulp because thats the automation tool i use for tasks like these , but you can go ahead and explain your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am assigned with the task of checking that there are no links which have no href, and empty href, or have an empty fragment as an href.

If that's all you require, you don't really need any gulp plugins. And it's doubtful that you will find something that fits your specific requirements anyway.

You can accomplish this yourself pretty easily however. All you really have to do is:

1. Read in all the HTML files you want to validate using [`gulp.src()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options).
2. Pipe each file to a function of your own using [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2).
3. Parse each file using any HTML parser you like (e.g. [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)).
4. Find the bad links in the parsed HTML DOM.
5. Log the bad links using [`gutil.log()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#logmsg) so you will know what to fix.
6. Maybe throw a [`gutil.PluginError`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#new-pluginerrorpluginname-message-options) so your build fails (this is optional).

Here's a Gulpfile that does exactly that (referencing the above points in comments):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2').obj;
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var path = require('path');

var checkLinks = function() {
  return through(function(file, enc, cb) { // [2]
    var badLinks = [];
    var $ = cheerio.load(file.contents.toString()); // [3]
    $('a').each(function() {
      var $a = $(this);
      if (!$a.attr('href') || $a.attr('href') == '#') { // [4]
        badLinks.push($.html($a));
      }
    });
    if (badLinks.length > 0) {
      var filePath = path.relative(file.cwd, file.path);
      badLinks.forEach(function(badLink) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(filePath + ': ' + badLink)); // [5]
      });
      throw new gutil.PluginError( 'checkLinks',
        badLinks.length + ' bad links in ' + filePath); // [6]
    }
    cb();
  });
}

gulp.task('checkLinks', function() {
  gulp.src('Gulp-Test/**/*.html') // [1]
    .pipe(checkLinks());
});
```

Running `gulp checkLinks` with a `Gulp-Test/index.html` like so ...

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<a>no href</a>
<a href="">empty href</a>
<a href="#">empty fragment</a>
<a href="#hash">non-empty fragment</a>
<a href="link.html">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

... results in the following output:

```
[20:01:08] Using gulpfile ~/example/gulpfile.js
[20:01:08] Starting 'checkLinks'...
[20:01:08] Finished 'checkLinks' after 21 ms
[20:01:08] Gulp-Test/index.html: <a>no href</a>
[20:01:08] Gulp-Test/index.html: <a href="">empty href</a>
[20:01:08] Gulp-Test/index.html: <a href="#">empty fragment</a>

/home/sven/example/gulpfile.js:22
      throw new gutil.PluginError( 'checkLinks',
      ^
Error: 3 bad links in Gulp-Test/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jsdom= require('jsdom').jsdom;

var fs=require('fs');

var colors= require('colors');

colors.setTheme({

  error:"red",

  file:"blue",

  info:"green",

  warn:"yellow"
});


gulp.task('checkLinks',function() {


  fs.readdir('.',function(err, files){

    if(err)
      throw err;


    var htmlFiles=files.filter(function(c,i,a){

      return c.substring(c.lastIndexOf('.')+1)==="html";

    });

    htmlFiles.forEach(function(c,i,a){

      fs.readFile(c,function(fileReadErr,data){

        if(fileReadErr)
          throw fileReadErr;

        var doc= jsdom(data);

        var window= doc.defaultView;

        var $=require('jquery')(window);

        var aTags=$('a').toArray(); 

        var k=0;

        console.log(("\n\n************************Checking File "+c+"***************************").info);

        for(var i=0; i<aTags.length; i++){

          if(!(aTags[i].hasAttribute("href")) || aTags[i].getAttribute("href")==="" || aTags[i].getAttribute("href")==="#" ) {

             k++;

             console.log("BAD LINK ".error+aTags[i].outerHTML.info+" IN FILE "+c.file);

          }
        }

        console.log(("BAD-LINKS COUNT IN " +c+" is "+k).bgRed.white);

        window.close();

      });
    });
  });

});
```

output:

[image: output of script above]